# building intuition of trajectories from visualization of phase portrait

Tags: dynamical-systems, visualization

lets say we have a system of ordinary differential equations and want to how the trajectories starting from all possible initial states evolve, without theoretically proving any properties (e.g. stability) of equilibrium and so on. This would be good for building intuitions before trying to prove certain properties, e.g. global asymptotic stability of an equilibrium. Thus I am wondering what is usual way to observe the trajectories computationally?

i was thinking that: set a lot of  initial conditions and simulate those trajectories starting from them, so I can get the phase portrait. is this the usual way? I think streamplots can help. is there any package/software specialized for doing this? if the gradient of basin of attraction can be visualized, then better.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you classify all the stationary points, you can kind of “connect the dots” to draw a phase portrait. I suppose you want something more than that? I guess computing some solutions numerically, as you suggested, can give you a more accurate phase portrait.

Comment: @littleO Thank you! yes I think visualizing the trajectories is the most direct way ... I was expecting that i can observe phase space in more detail. let's say there is a local attractor (asymptotic stable equilibrium) on the state space, what is the geometric properties (e.g. curvature, depth, and so on) of its basin. I guess using streamplot couldn't give a very detailed visualization of this... so was thinking whether there is another way.